# Are vocal critique questions acceptable?

Tags: discussion, support

Are questions which have an audio/video recording with the request for critiquing of vocal performance acceptable? I think this can be generalized based on the response dealing with common problems.

Comment: I really really do not understand the downvote. I would understood it if an off-topic question was actually asked, but this is just a request on advice. Especially in a beta site, completely reasonable one.

Comment: @yo' Downvotes on meta are different--they usually just indicate an opinion in the negative. I.e. whoever is responsible for the downvote just thinks that "no, those questions would not be appropriate for the main site."

Comment: @NReilingh Which would, IMHO, be the appropriate thing to do if it was a feature request.

Comment: @NReilingh But this is a question, asking for us to give opinions. The downvote means effectively nothing, and it prevents the question to reach the sidebar. Some people just downvote because they don't like the question, the asker, or they don't want the question to reach the sidebar (maybe they are involved in a non-positive way). It happens in all meta SEs.

Answer (score 6):

Critiquing a performance would not be appropriate as all the response would be completely opinionated and subjective. If these were allowed, how would the user select a correct response? The one with the most up votes? This kind of thing is better left elsewhere.

Comment: In addition I disagree with OP's idea that it could be generalized.  Even if the answers identify and address common issues, that doesn't affect the question -- which would be completely unsearchable and useless to others.

Comment: @MatthewRead perhaps OP meant that the submitted recording might be held as an example of common problems that other's may also learn from.  It would be hard to reference or research though (which I think is what your are saying) - as the identified problems would only be in the answer's and not in the question and the answers would only be useful to those who listened to the recording and read the answers and found the identified problems to be problems they had as well.  So the value would occur only through happenstance and accident.