# Can we add "Vocal critique" to our list of 'and not about' in the Help/on topic page?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, topics, help-center

Ref: https://music.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic
We have quite a specific list of 'do not ask' in the help, better defined than many sites - but we still get the occasional 'how good is my voice?' type question.

It's already long-established that these are off-topic… but it doesn't actually say so anywhere, so we can't just point to the help as backup.

Could we add that topic to the list?  or not just vocal critique, but any critique - it just seems vocal is favourite amongst new askers.
Suggestions for wording welcome, I don't have anything very specific in mind.

Established precedent:
[Are vocal critique questions acceptable?](https://music.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2086/are-vocal-critique-questions-acceptable)
[Are we allowed to post videos here for your music to be critiqued?](https://music.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3041/are-we-allowed-to-post-videos-here-for-your-music-to-be-critiqued)

See [Suggestion for 'critique' wording for help/on topic](https://music.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3979/suggestion-for-critique-wording-for-help-on-topic) for actual wording suggestions.

Comment: I would also include "What type is my voice?" in this.

Comment: A good place to propose ideas might be [Updating close reasons to fit the new format](https://music.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3816/70803). In particular, see [my proposal](https://music.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3821/70803) from Jan 2022.

Comment: @Aaron - but I'm not proposing a new close reason, I'm proposing a change to the Help page.

Comment: With vocals it's not only opinion based, but also a wrong or misunderstood advice can particularly easily lead to an injury. We cannot accept such questions for the same reasons we don't accept requests for medical advice. But as you say, "opinion based" is a valid close reason for such questions, we don't need a new option.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think this is an excellent idea.

We have the existing meta posts, which seem to agree, and the various vocal critique questions we see are almost entirely opinion-based. Even those that aren't would be better served by going to see a vocal coach in person, so they could see and hear exactly what was happening.

Comment: The advice should include something along the lines of "When you have enough reputation, this question can be posted in the chat room." These questions seem to generate interest from both askers and answerers, so even though they don't fit the main site, we should let people know where they are welcome.

Comment: Do we need another meta post to hammer out an agreement on wording? If so, do you want to kick off, or shall I? I don't really have anything concrete in mind, so I don't mind if someone else wants to get that ball rolling.

Comment: Maybe this should be extended to instrumental and compositional critique as well.

Comment: @PiedPiper I agree about instrumental critique. Not composition critique, however, since the OP can learn lots of music theory from such questions

Answer (score 5):

Yes please! The questions such as -am I a tenor, or have I a good voice, are no real help - not usually even to the OP. We need to specify that this kind of question isn't a good fit for this site. Soon!

Answer (score 4):

Yes.

These questions and those like it are some of the most commonly reposted questions here. I'm absolutely sick and tired of seeing them at this point.

Answer (score 2):

I know this question has been open for a while, but I wanted to throw in a few cents.

I think the biggest problem with such questions is their *open-endedness*, and I'd like to see any help-page language include something along those lines, like "... and are not about ... general requests for critique or advice, without a clear and specific concern." It's kind of similar to a guideline on [English Language and Usage](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), where general "Hey, proofread this paragraph" questions are off-topic, but "am I using this word right?" is ok (if it's not easily googlable and is clearly communicated and is not a dupe, yada yada).

I'd want to head off at the pass votes to close questions that could share some hallmarks with these "critique" questions but that I would think would be okay. Like, say, "When I try to do a barre chord I get this buzz and my wrist hurts; here's a video of me trying." Just because it contains a recording of the OP doesn't make it a "critique question"; it has a specific concern and could have clear, valid answers. Even if the OP added "Am I doing it right?" it wouldn't have the open-endedness that makes "Hey, whaddaya think of my range" questions impossible to answer definitively.

Comment: i've no objection to that. I did post a subsequent question on what the actual wording might be - https://music.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3979/suggestion-for-critique-wording-for-help-on-topic